# eval in anchor tag href

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, eval

What I am trying to achieve is to use an Eval as parameter in my anchor tag's href. The anchor is nested inside a repeater, why I cannot use the code behind to achieve this.

I have tried a few things without any luck.

```
<a href="http://MyWebsite/ActiveUsers?ID=InsertEvalHere"><%# Eval("Name")%></a>
```

The following code below is what I have tried to do:

```
<a href="<% "http://MyWebsite/ActiveUsers?ID=" + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem("ID"))%>"><%# Eval("Name")%></a>

<a href="<% "http://MyWebsite/ActiveUsers?ID=" + Eval("ID")%>"><%# Eval("Name")%></a>

<a href="http://MyWebsite/ActiveUsers?ID=<% DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem("ID"))%>"><%# Eval("Name")%></a>

<a href="http://MyWebsite/ActiveUsers?ID=<%# Eval("ID")%>"><%# Eval("Name")%></a>
```

None of the above seemed to be right, as I keep getting this error - **The tag is not well formed.**

How should I handle this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
<a href="<%# String.Format("http://MyWebsite/ActiveUsers?ID={0}", Eval("ID")) %>">
```

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
<a href='http://MyWebsite/ActiveUsers?ID=<%# Eval(Container.DataItem("ID"))%>'><%# Eval("Name")%></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotation and move the url out like this

```
<a href='http://MyWebsite/ActiveUsers?ID=<% DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem("ID"))%>'><%# Eval("Name")%></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

a bit late but....

```
<a href='<%# Eval("ID","http://MyWebsite/ActiveUsers?ID={0}") %>'><%# Eval("Name")%></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need access the anchor in code behind for enabling and disabling it based on condition at datalist_ItemDataBound , then you can use the way provided by [Nicky Waites](https://stackoverflow.com/users/98589/nicky-waites) with a small change as shown below

```
<a id="register" runat="server" href='<%# String.Format("http://MyWebsite/ActiveUsers?ID={0}", Eval("ID")) %>'>
```

Hope this would help someone.

Answer (score 0):

In your repeater, use this:

```
CommandName="Apikey" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("POAPI")%>'
```

And access in the code behind.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thank you for your contribution. Why do you prefer this articulation over e.g. the accepted answer?