# ASP Server Tag Error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am quite new to ASP.Net and C# and

i am trying to perform this server tag: 
 `<a id="A1" href="javascript:edit(" + <%#Eval("ID")%> + ")" runat="server">Some Text</a>` 
 but its not working --> with this `href` i get the Error:

`The server tag is not well formed.`

I know it is a common problem. I've been searching for hours and i found some soulutions. For example this one:

[eval in anchor tag href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536956/eval-in-anchor-tag-href)

but it didn't work. So i kept searching and found this:

[href='News.aspx?id=<%#Eval("id")%>' not work in LinkButton ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9348006/href-news-aspxid-evalid-not-work-in-linkbutton-asp-net)

i have no idea what could work. I also tried the href attribute with sigle quotes:
`<a id="A1" href='javascript:edit(<%#Eval("ID")%>)' runat="server"></a>`
and got this output in the `<a></a>`:

```
)" id="content_gvMain_A1_8">Test
```

So my questions are:
Do i have to change some config?
Or are there better Server Tags?
Is it possible to `Eval()` in a href ?

## Solution

I found a working solution:

`<a id="A1" href='<%# "javascript:Edit(" + Eval("ID") + ")" %>' runat="server">Some Text</a>`

Comment: @Rubens Farias it is not a duplicate, because href is not a js function and btw i also tried this solution and it gives me the same error

Comment: Maybe, you can learn something from this link
[using a href to call javascript function with parameter][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6793159/using-a-href-to-call-javascript-function-with-parameter

Comment: The difference is you have the `href` attribute and the other answer had the `onblur`; use the same technique.